# Creating a text file in Resources

Tags: c#, resources

Is a way to create a text file in `Resources` programmatically?

Comment: Why would you want it in resources and not just store it somewhere on the drive, like in the application data directory?

Comment: I'm trying to make a program that would work only using the .exe file

Comment: Then why do you need to add it programmatically? Maybe if you explained in more detail what you really want to do, we can help, as it is now, this sounds like an X-Y problem (trying to solve the wrong problem).

Comment: You can embed your resources in your exe file inserting them in the project. When compiling the resources will become part of your exe file as result of building process.
But you cannot, at runtime, create a new resource or modify an existing one: this would mean modify the exe file itself, which is not possible.
Resources are meant to be used for something set at compile time, at run time use something else (file, setting, etc)

Comment: Well basically what my program need to do is to create a text file with stuff on it and then later use it for other things

Comment: So you want to write a variable to a text file, then read that variable from the text file at a later point?

Comment: Pretty much yes but not to a already existing text file

Comment: So you want to create a brand new file each time. Or do you mean create a single file for use by your application, and use that to transfer information.

Comment: Yes I want to create a brand new file, but I need it to be created in resources

Comment: If you're going to create a new file each time, have you decided how to name them?

Comment: What type of data are you going to be saving to these files?

Comment: The user would decide how to name them

Comment: Well It's going to be a text file so some strings

Comment: When you say resources, do you mean the application resources that get compiled away, or just a general "resource folder"?

Comment: The application resources

Comment: At run time, you cannot add files to the application's resources see @Gian Paolo's comment. You can however, create a new folder at runtime, put the user generated files in there, and let the application read from this folder at a later point.

Comment: Oh okay. Well thanks anyway and sorry for wasting your time